# Stuck at ntdll when trying to enter a game loop

Tags: debugging

I'm new to reverse enginnering and currently following Lena's tutorials. I wanted to put my new skills to use and wanted to reverse a simple game: https://github.com/Zolomon/labyrinth.

I think I'm stuck somewhere in ntdll. How do I get out of that? It's after the game as been instantiated then everything stops working.

I was hoping I would be stuck in the game loop and from there I was hoping to capture in-game movements.

Below is a picture where I've put breakpoints right before the game window is created. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the main module by going to "View -> Executable Modules" and selecting it instead of "ntdll".

Comment: Thanks, Dvd848! I managed to go back to the main module, however I lost track of where I was. I mean from being back I cannot step over or step in.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint at the next instruction of the main module and then performing some action in the game UI. That might cause the current function to return and allow you to proceed stepping (assuming the current function is waiting for some user interaction).